# PHP: Save Dynamic URL Image to Disk

Tags: php, curl

Having trouble capturing the following dynamic image on disk, all I get is a 1K size file

http://water.weather.gov/precip/save.php?timetype=RECENT&loctype=NWS&units=engl&timeframe=current&product=observed&loc=regionER

I have setup PHP cURL feature to work just fine on static imagery, but does not work for the above link.  Similarly, also copy function, file_put_contents (file_get_contents)...they all work fine for static image.  Plenty of references in SO for usage of these PHP functions, so I will not get into details here.  Just the copy command:

```
copy('http://water.weather.gov/precip/save.php?timetype=RECENT&loctype=NWS&units=engl&timeframe=current&product=observed&loc=regionER', 'precip5.png');
```

Behavior is same, getting precip5.png size 760 bytes, on my windows development box and linux staging box, so can rule OS issues out. Again, all PHP functions do exactly the same thing - generate a file - but empty. Command line curl program is also generating that same junk 1K file.

So, the issue seems to be source and the best I can tell is that it is a dynamic (streaming?) image.

Ideally, I would like this be done in PHP or some command line utility like curl.  I am trying to avoid adding java (imageio) dependency just for this...until I absolutely have have to go there...

I am trying to understand the nature of the beast (the image) first ;-)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are saving produces HTML output, not the image. You are missing the parameter `&print=1`

```
http://water.weather.gov/precip/save.php?timetype=RECENT&loctype=NWS&units=engl&timeframe=current&product=observed&loc=regionER&print=1
```

Comment: Wow, that was it!  Mystified, though:  Is save.php such a well known utility or convention - ? -  Not only is the print parameter is known, but also that its value is to be set to 1?  Can you elaborate on that?  How did you fathom that?  Thanks!!

Comment: I clicked on your link and then on "View page source" in the browser. You can see the HTML with the link to the actual image there. You would have seen it too if you had opened your "corrupt" image file in a text editor.

Comment: Aah - OK.  So, the image sort of fooled me.  The dynamic part was actually an html page - within nothing but the image in it - so I mistook the browser URL to be image source, when it was actually a page.  The real image source was embedded within that that page.  No magic, all transparent.  Thanks, again.